# [PYTHON]Looking to plot launch speed vs. launch angle on a scatterplot (baseball) and I don't know how to color them by pitch type using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

launch_speed = [launch_speed_values]
launch_angle = [launch_angle_values]

pitch_type = ['Sinker', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Knuckle Curve', 'Changeup', 'Sinker', 'Slider', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Sinker', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', 'Changeup', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Sinker', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Knuckle Curve', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', 'Slider', 'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Curveball', 'Sinker', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Cutter', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Cutter', 
'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', 'Sinker', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Slider', 'Knuckle Curve', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', 'Slider', 'Slider', 'Cutter', 'Sinker', 'Sinker', 'Sinker', 'Sinker', 'Sinker',  'Slider', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 
'Cutter', 'Slider', 'Sinker', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', 'Changeup', '4-Seam Fastball', '4-Seam Fastball']

plt.scatter(launch_speed_launch_angle)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I want to have different colors for each type of pitch e.g. '4-Seam Fastball', 'Changeup', etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a graph by looping through the data in a scatter plot and specifying a sphere for the label. I created a sample data frame at random, so if the data frame is similar, you can draw the graph as it is.

```
import pandas as pd
launch_speed = [145.2, 137.6, 152.9, 148.7, 129.6, 136.6]
launch_angle = [7.5, 8.2, 9.5, 12.3, 5.5, 8.8]
pitch_types = ['Sinker','Slider','Changeup','Slider','4-Seam Fastball','Sinker']

df = pd.DataFrame({'launch_speed':launch_speed,'launch_angle':launch_angle,'pitch_type':pitch_types})

df
launch_speed    launch_angle    pitch_type
0   145.2   7.5 Sinker
1   137.6   8.2 Slider
2   152.9   9.5 Changeup
3   148.7   12.3    Slider
4   129.6   5.5 4-Seam Fastball
5   136.6   8.8 Sinker

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for k,d in df.groupby('pitch_type'):
    ax.scatter(d['launch_speed'], d['launch_angle'], label=k)

ax.set_xlabel('Speed', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Angle', fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Speed and Pitch Type')
ax.legend(loc=2)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]